# Phonegap battery plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm currently trying to implement cordova's battery plugin to show the current battery life and state of the battery. I have found a code that fires only when there is a change in percentage for battery life. How do I permanently show what percentage or state the battery is at on a particular page on a mobile device?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var statusdiv;

        var drawStatus = function(info){
            var s = "<p><b>Battery Status</b><br/>";
            s += "Level is "+info.level + "<br/>";
            s += "Plugged in is "+info.isPlugged;
            s += "</p>";
            statusdiv.innerHTML = s;
        };

    var battCrit = function(info) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Your battery is SUPER low!");
            drawStatus(info);
        };

    var battLow = function(info) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Your battery is low!");
            drawStatus(info);
        };

    var battStat = function(info) {
            drawStatus(info);
        };
     var onDeviceReady = function() {
            //listen for battery events
            window.addEventListener("batterycritical", battCrit, false);
            window.addEventListener("batterylow", battLow, false);
            window.addEventListener("batterystatus", battStat, false);
};

function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            statusdiv = document.getElementById("status");
} 
     </script> 
</head>


<body onload="init();">

<h2>Battery Tester</h2>

    <div id="status"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ashley,
the phonegap plugin for the battery works just as you described it. There is no other way to get any more readings from that plugin. Your app is working to the extent of the plugin.

Is there something else you want to do? It is not clear, if and what you want to do.

Jesse

Comment: is there a way to display the battery status in the application permanently? When i relaunch my application it does not show the status of the battery

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, just use the callback.

However, I think you want to update the status when the App is in the background. As such, you can have the App run in the background and have the battery status updated. However, if you App stops, such as when Android removes your App from the running queue, then your App will restart from scratch - as if in never ran.

Currently, I am working on something similar. I have a [battery status demo App](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Battery-Test), but it stops when it is not in the foreground. My app will work in the background (once I  fix this) and log the battery status to [localstorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Again, I think you want background operation, which is what I will be using. To get background operation you will need to modify [config.xml](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File) and add an [Android.xml extension](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration). **NOTE**: if you are using *Phonegap Build*, you will need to use [different docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29) (for phonegap build use [config-file Element](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification_config_file_element))

So, if you want background operation, I will do this sometime this month or next month. If you cannot wait, the permission you will need on Android is on the link below.

*Manifest.permission*
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html